# Protobuf: How to combine FieldOptions with Default Values in Messages

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a message using FieldOptions but I also want to use default values as well, how do I combine two of those things ?

```
extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
    optional FlagDetail info = 1234;
}

message TestCmd {
    optional bool BoolFlag = 1 [(info) = { name: "bool-flag" value: "false" shorthand: "c" usage: "test"} ];
    optional string StringFlag = 2 [ (info) = { name: "string-flag" value: "" shorthand: "o" usage: "test"}];
}
```

I want that TestCmd.BoolFlag default value to be bool value  "false", currently I'm using string value then convert it to bool, How do I
specify the default value in a type-safe way ?

Thanks

Comment: Default values are specified via `default=false` inside the square brackets; if you have multiple tokens, they are comma separated; is this what you mean? It is hard to grok because the custom option you are showing (`msg`) is not the one you are using (`info`). But `[(info) = {...}, default = false]`

Comment: oh, sorry, It's a FieldOptions, I will update my question